# Is there a faster way to close these holes

Tags: modeling, topology, 3d-printing

I'm working on this statue, I started it as two separate objects, the lion and the orix, I merged them to one object using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>, I need to connect the mesh properly so it can be 3D printed, and later I will use Sculpt to make the details, I've been moving, edge looping and connecting all these vertices manually, but it's an extremely tedious job, is there a better way to merge or connect all these vertices and remove the excess resulting edges? The problem isn't only with the long time it takes, but with each edge loop added, I'm increasing the faces count, and I'm trying to keep it as low as possible.
[image: Object mode]

[[image: From inside][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb9Ak.png)

[image: Holes in mesh[![][3]]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSdBE.png)

Comment: Can you post the Blend? Prior to the merging of the meshes?

Comment: How do I do that Rick Riggs?

Comment: I added a link on sketchfab, I uploaded the OBJ file before merging the objects.

Comment: If the sculpture were a bit more flat it could be possible shrinkwrap a plane atop of these 2 meshes. In this case I don't think it's solution, so if you'd like *less polys* and meshes *connected* to each other, use **Boolean** or **Knife Project** to cut statue into the base with using Ngons to lower amount of faces. If the area of connecting is going to be flat nothing should be wrong.

Comment: I'm with Mr Zak on one point, looking at your mesh it looks like a simplistic enough mesh to successfully pull of boolean operations, which is why I wanted to see if your geometry was closed before you joined it. You mentioned that you had holes, where those introduced when you started hacking away at the joined mesh, or where they there to begin with?

Comment: If you have the blender file, this would be ideal, as you need to join sketchfab just to download the files. To add it use the following [LINK](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: Thank you Mr Zak, I'll research these methods and try them.

Comment: Rick Riggs, I meant by the holes, the difference between the edges of the two meshes after I merged them, as in the images.

Comment: I uploaded the .blend file, and linked it to the question url

Comment: @Georges please don't make us log in on other website (or create an account on it) to try to help you...

Comment: @cegaton, I didn't know how to upload the .blend file, when Rick Riggs gave me the link, I did upload the .blend file to blender-exchange and linked to the url here, but I can't find it anywhere! I only added the sketchfab link when Rick Riggs asked for the file, this was the only way I knew how to do it.

Comment: @MrZak and Rick Riggs I used the Boolean method on the separate objects after closing the meshes, it's awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @Georges http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a boolean modifier to merge the two objects. You might have a few new vertices in your mesh but it will be far easier to clean up once you have deleted the inner faces created in the operation.

Comment: I used this method, in my case it is the most useful method

Answer (score 1):

I'm constantly editing similar meshes, I usually subdivide smooth (meshes absorb to each other), then laplacian smooth, remove doubles and then maybe laplacian smooth again. Play around with the Lambda factor in laplacian smooth to get the desired result. Lessoning the vertices in the less visible areas is always a good idea.